# How do you pass ABI-encoded parameters to abi.encodeWithSignature / abi.encodeWithSelector as a single bytes object?

Tags: solidity, abi

Given a function `setXY(uint256 x, uint256 y)`, how can I encode data parameters `x` and `y` into a single `bytes data` array that can be fed into `abi.encodeWithSignature('setXY(uint256,uint256)', data)`?

Ethers has an [ABI encoder](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/abi/coder/#AbiCoder-encode) that allows for encoding array values according to array types. This allows encoding parameters via `abiCoder.encode(['uint256', 'uint256'], ['1', '2'])` into a `bytes` array.

But, feeding this as `data` into `abi.encodeWithSignature` or `abi.encodeWithSelector` results in `data` being read incorrectly,  likely due to `abi.encode` leaving leading zeros for each argument.

Is there any way of accomplishing this correctly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot use `bytes data` because it will be encoded as an array, and you want to  encode two uint256 instead.

```
uint256 x = 1324;
uint256 y = 4444;
abi.encodeWithSignature('setXY(uint256,uint256)', x, y);
```

Comment: Given I want to feed all data into `abi.encodeWithSignature('setXY(uint256,uint256)', data)`, is there any way to encode arguments as an array? E.g. encoding x and y here as a single bytes array, with ethers tooling?

Comment: @Leeren Using `abi.encodeWithSignature` is not possible because the [contract ABI](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.9/abi-spec.html) encode uints and arrays are differently. You could use `abi.encodePacked` instead.